# Installing dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on separate disks

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ssd

I have a new computer. It has a 128GB SSD with Windows 10 pre-installed on it. It also has a 1TB HDD. I would like to install Ubuntu on a partition (say 100GB) on the HDD for a dual-boot. I would like to be prompted which OS I want to boot on start-up.

I have searched for this online, but everyone seems to be saying something else, from just installing Ubuntu to manually setting up partitions and adding all sorts of entries in Grub.

Are there any problems I am overlooking? What makes the tutorials diverge so much from one another?

Comment: I would expect 1TB drive to also be gpt partitioned, but if SSD is you need to make sure. Grub always defaults to the ESP on sda, but will just create a new /EFI/ubuntu folder and will not normally interfere with Windows or vice-versa. But some UEFI work better at booting Ubuntu than others. With second drive always better to use Something Else. Otherwise the auto install option may not do what you expect. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score -1):

You would have to change the boot order of the drives depending on which OS you wish to boot if they are on separate drives.

If not then yes, you will need to add entries into GRUB.

Your best option would be to either:

A. Install Ubuntu, and Windows 10 on the SSD (Allocated 64GB to each which, should be plenty for the OS as long as if you have your /home on the HDD).

B. Install Ubuntu, and Windows 10 on the HDD and have your /home on the SSD, and install Windows programs to the SSD for faster load times.

Sadly, you will not be able to put both on separate drives without doing some type of work to it.

(Please note: I could be completely incorrect on this, but from personal experience, I have not been able to do this on 2 separate drives and still have an option to choose which OS I'd like to open from GRUB. However in BIOS, you will have that option).

Comment: I have multiple installs of Ubuntu in UEFI mode on both sda & sdb. But in UEFI boot mode everything boots from the ESP - efi system partition on sda. Grub always defaults to that.

Comment: Completely forgot about that, sorry.